# Angular 4 ngIf not toggled after variable being updated in ngOnInit

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-ng-if

I am using Angular v4 and have a *ngIf in my template:

```html
<div class="product-list row" *ngIf="products.length > 0">
  <div *ngFor="let product of products" class="product-container">
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

and in my component file I have:

```
public products = [];

....

public ngOnInit(): void {
  this.productsService.all().toPromise().then( (data: Product[]) => {
    this.products = data;
  });
}
```

However the ngIf will not be toggled after `products` is set. When I add a button and set the variables manually the ngIf will be toggled!

I tried changing the if statement to `products?.length > 0` but it doesn't work as well.

Comment: do you see this.products when you add a console.log?

Comment: Try `this.products = [...data]`

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes I did see this.products in console.log. The value is being set but the ngIf is not toggled.

Comment: @chrisz Doesn't work... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer from this post:
[Triggering change detection manually in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34827334/triggering-change-detection-manually-in-angular)

According to Angular's documents https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef

`detectChanges(): Checks the change detector and its children.`

So by applying detectChanges Angular will manually check and update the node.